# SQL Min displaying all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query selecting data from a temp table which is set out below

```
SELECT  Ref,
        YOA,
        Account,
        Cert,
        MIN(Unit) AS Unit,
        Name
        Currency,
        Amount

FROM #TMP_Accounts

GROUP BY    Ref,
            YOA,
            Account,
            Cert,
            Name,
            Currency,
            Amount
```

When I run this query I get the following results:

```
Ref     YOA     Account Cert     Unit Name Currency Amount
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    1   US  CAD  25,167,555
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    3   FR  CAD  25,167,555.56
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    4   DE  CAD  25,167,555.56
```

What I am stuck on is the fact that when I use the MIN function I want to pull back one record for Unit value 1 but instead I'm getting 3 records. I have been through this column by column and the additional records only seem to appear when I add in the Amount column.

When I do a simple select * from I get the following:

```
Ref     YOA     Account Cert     Unit Name Currency  Amount
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    1   US   CAD     25,167,555.00
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    2   UK   CAD     25,167,555.00
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    3   FR   CAD     25,167,555.56
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    4   DE   CAD     25,167,555.56
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    5   AU   CAD     25,167,555.56
1924403 2017    ABCXYZ  PFA96417    6   NZ   CAD     25,167,555.56
```

So I know its being aggregated to a point, just not to the min unit value I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting tip: When editing, type in proper columns. Mark the text and click `{}`.

Comment: I think your problem in in your group by - grouping by currency is forcing it to return the three records

Comment: What do you want to see for the amount if there is more than one Unit 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to join the table by itself

```
select a.* from #TMP_Accounts a
inner join (select min(unit) as minunit from #TMP_Accounts) b
on a.Unit = b.minunit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the row with the minimum number of units, you can use:

```
select top (1) a.*
from #TMP_Accounts a
order by units;
```

The `group by` is definitely causing your problem.  It may not be appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: I like this version better since for the hopefully *rare* scenario where your table is a HEAP, this would perform better / best (out of the answers so far).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation I think you're looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #TMP_Accounts
WHERE Unit = (SELECT MIN(Unit) FROM #TMP_Accounts)
```

This doesn't necessarily return one row, since for duplicate rows with the same minimum value you will get those 2 rows back. However, how this scenario should be handled isn't clear from your question.